# Delay the foreach Loop in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, foreach

I hope you are well. I am getting data from one API and sending to Shopify store API. As its working fine but its entering some products as when it iterates in the loop API is busy with index suppose 0,1,2 and then indexes 3,4,...10 bypassed. So , according to me I should delay the foreach loop with 10,15 seconds. Please help me to do this . I tried it many times with SETTimer etc but foreach loop structure is difficult for me as a new person. Please check the below code. Thanks

```
const request = require('request');
const { json } = require('express');
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');
const fastcsv = require('fast-csv');
//const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const { privateDecrypt } = require('crypto');
const { time } = require('console');



const fields = ['Vendor', 'Price', 'SKU','error'];


const opts = { fields };
 
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
  path: 'C:/Users/IT City/Desktop/arslan.csv',
  header: [
    {id: 'Vendor', title: 'Vendor'},
    {id: 'Price', title: 'Price'},
    {id: 'SKU', title: 'SKU'},
    {id: 'error', title: 'error'},
  ]
});

let new_products = {
  product_final: {
    Vendor: String,
    Price: String,
    SKU: String,
    Error: String,
  }
};
//////////First API from which I am getting the data

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.dexi.io/runs/f58f7795-c11a-478c-b670-c7ae5df8677b/latest/result',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    json: true,
    'x-dexiio-access': '9d56e967dfXXXXXXX725e234b311655c96',
    'x-dexiio-account': '5e597feb-99axxxxxxxx-37f1315723ab'
  }
};




products = ['Vendor','Price','SKU','Error']
let product = {};
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  pro = JSON.parse(body);
 
/////Looping through the each Item from the first API and sending data to Shopify. But its entering only 10-12 products 
//// As handle is busy to entering the product.
/// I have to delay the foreach loop 10, 15 seconds

pro.rows.forEach(       
  
  row => { 
    
    
        for (let z = 0; z < row.length; z++) 
        {
            product[pro.headers[z]] = row[z];
            product_final2[pro.headers[z]] = row[z];
        }
         
      
        productssdata.push(product_final2)
        
        products.push(product)
       
        var Price = product.Price;
        var SKU = product.SKU;
        var Vendor = product.Vendor;
        var body_html = "THISFSDFSDFSDFSDFSFSDF";

        
            
             let new_products = {
              product: {
                title: Vendor,
                body_html: Price,
                vendor: Vendor,
                product_type: SKU,
                tags: Price
              }
            };
                    
            const options = {
            
            method: 'POST',
            url: 
            'https://0abcfsdfsdf4bb6532f3b@amjad.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-07/products.json',
            headers: {
            accept: 'application/json',
            'apiKey': '07649cABSDCCSD8ffbae7af02',
            'password': 'sSDCSDFDF',
            body: new_products,
            json: true,
            
            };
         
          request(options, function (error, response, body) {
          
          if (error) throw new Error(error);
          console.log(body)
          
          });
          
      
          }

);



}




);
```

Comment: hope you know JS is async in nature, you will need callback/ promise/ async-await to make it synchronous

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use setTimeOut() to delay the loop. thats what async and await are for let me share you an example how to make the forEach loop delay with await!!.
step1 : return a function with promise and use await until it is complete.

```
    const wait =async props => {
    return new Promise((reslove,reject) => {
    return reslove(Math.random());       
})
```

}

```
       const x = [1,2,3,4]
       x.forEach(async number =>{
       const num = await wait();
       console.log('start')
       console.log(num);
       console.log('end');
```

})

Answer (score 0):

1. Request is [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)
2. It can't be used with `await` anyway, which makes it inconvenient. There used to be another module, [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise), that as wrapping `request` and return a Promise, so one could `await` it, but it's still deprecated.
3. For these reasons, use [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or Fetch instead
4. You can't use `await` or delay a `.forEach()` loop, but you can in a `for` loop.
5. You think you need to delay the calls, because they are asynchronous, but in reality you should simply await each call. Delaying calls with an arbitrary timeout is a dirty workaround.

In the end, you can do something like :

```
( async () => {

    let options = {
        url : "http://......"
    };

    const response = await axios.get(options); // Add try/catch block around this to manage errors

    const pro = response.data;

    for( let row of pro.rows) {

        options = {
            url : "http://some.other.url"
        }

        const response = await axios.get(options); // Each call will be done one by one and awaited in order
    }
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(pro.rows.forEach((row) => {...}), 10000)
```

This executes the forEach after 10 seconds.

Comment: Hi Dharman , Thanks for the comment but I applied this code and getting the below error results "internal/validators.js:189
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(callback);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined"